# How to simulate real key typing action in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm automating a web application where i have to fill the credit card details to complete the checkout process. I'm able to enter credit card number successfully but it shows me validation error in application that credit card number is not valid. While i do type the number manually it doesn't show.

This is the HTML:

```html
<div dimensions="[object Object]" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-flow: row wrap; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 1; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; flex-grow: 1;"><label for="cardNumber"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: row; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; height: 60px; justify-content: space-between; padding: 15px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color: rgb(150, 147, 145); border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; width: 508px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; align-self: center; height: 20px; padding-right: 15px;"><svg focusable="false" height="20" width="20"><g transform="translate(0, 0) scale(1)"><path d="M17,16 L3,16 C2.449,16 2,15.551 2,15 L2,9 L18,9 L18,15 C18,15.551 17.551,16 17,16 M3,4 L17,4 C17.551,4 18,4.449 18,5 L18,6 L2,6 L2,5 C2,4.449 2.449,4 3,4 M17,2 L3,2 C1.346,2 0,3.346 0,5 L0,15 C0,16.654 1.346,18 3,18 L17,18 C18.654,18 20,16.654 20,15 L20,5 C20,3.346 18.654,2 17,2" fill="rgba(120, 117, 115, 1)" style="transition: fill 0.2s ease 0s;"></path><path d="M16,12.5 C16,13.329 15.329,14 14.5,14 C13.671,14 13,13.329 13,12.5 C13,11.671 13.671,11 14.5,11 C15.329,11 16,11.671 16,12.5" fill="rgba(120, 117, 115, 1)" style="transition: fill 0.2s ease 0s;"></path><path d="M13,12.5 C13,13.329 12.329,14 11.5,14 C10.671,14 10,13.329 10,12.5 C10,11.671 10.671,11 11.5,11 C12.329,11 13,11.671 13,12.5" fill="rgba(120, 117, 115, 1)" style="transition: fill 0.2s ease 0s;"></path></g></svg></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 1; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; flex-grow: 0; top: -16px; width: 100%;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); margin-left: 0px; pointer-events: none; padding-left: 0px; width: 100%; transform: translateY(14px);"><span style="max-width: 100%; color: rgb(120, 117, 115); font-family: &quot;Klarna Text&quot;, &quot;Klarna Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; line-height: 30px; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision; text-size-adjust: none;">Card Number</span></div><input id="cardNumber" name="cardNumber" data-cid="card-number-field" autocomplete="cc-number" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" spellcheck="false" value="" style="background-color: transparent; border: none; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; width: 100%; box-shadow: none; caret-color: rgb(72, 123, 148); color: rgb(23, 23, 23); font-family: &quot;Klarna Text&quot;, &quot;Klarna Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; height: 60px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 20px; position: absolute; text-overflow: ellipsis; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision; transform: translateY(0px);"></div></div></label></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 1; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; flex-grow: 1;"><label for="expire"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: row; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; height: 60px; justify-content: space-between; padding: 15px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color: rgb(150, 147, 145); border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; margin-top: -1px; width: 254px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; align-self: center; height: 20px; padding-right: 15px;"><svg focusable="false" width="20" height="20"><g transform="translate(0, 0) scale(1)"><path d="M16,17 L4,17 C3.448,17 3,16.551 3,16 L3,9 L17,9 L17,16 C17,16.551 16.552,17 16,17 Z M5,4 L5,5 L7,5 L7,4 L13,4 L13,5 L15,5 L15,4 L17,4 L17,7 L3,7 L3,4 L5,4 Z M15,2 L15,1 L13,1 L13,2 L7,2 L7,1 L5,1 L5,2 L1,2 L1,16 C1,17.654 2.346,19 4,19 L16,19 C17.654,19 19,17.654 19,16 L19,2 L15,2 Z" fill="rgba(120, 117, 115, 1)" style="transition: fill 0.2s ease 0s;"></path><polygon points="5 14 9 14 9 11 5 11" fill="rgba(120, 117, 115, 1)" style="transition: fill 0.2s ease 0s;"></polygon></g></svg></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 1; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; flex-grow: 0; top: -16px; width: 100%;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); margin-left: 0px; pointer-events: none; padding-left: 0px; width: 100%; transform: translateY(14px);"><span style="max-width: 100%; color: rgb(120, 117, 115); font-family: &quot;Klarna Text&quot;, &quot;Klarna Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; line-height: 30px; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision; text-size-adjust: none;">MM / YY</span></div><input id="expire" name="expire" config="[object Object]" data-cid="card-expire-field" autocomplete="cc-exp" pattern="[0-9]*" spellcheck="false" type="tel" value="" style="background-color: transparent; border: none; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; width: 100%; box-shadow: none; caret-color: rgb(72, 123, 148); color: rgb(23, 23, 23); font-family: &quot;Klarna Text&quot;, &quot;Klarna Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; height: 60px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 20px; position: absolute; text-overflow: ellipsis; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision; transform: translateY(0px);"></div></div></label></div><input autocomplete="cc-exp-month" tabindex="-1" style="background-color: transparent; border: none; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; width: 100%; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; position: fixed; z-index: -1; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision;"><input autocomplete="cc-exp-year" tabindex="-1" style="background-color: transparent; border: none; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; width: 100%; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; position: fixed; z-index: -1; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision;"></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 1; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; flex-grow: 1;"><label for="securityCode"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: row; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; height: 60px; justify-content: space-between; padding: 15px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color: rgb(150, 147, 145); border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; width: 255px; margin-left: -1px; margin-top: -1px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; align-self: center; height: 20px; padding-right: 15px;"><svg focusable="false" height="20" width="20"><g transform="translate(0, 0) scale(1)"><path d="M15,15.547 C15,15.767 14.926,15.984 14.791,16.159 L13.669,17.611 C13.481,17.854 13.185,18 12.878,18 L7.122,18 C6.815,18 6.519,17.854 6.331,17.611 L5.209,16.159 C5.074,15.984 5,15.767 5,15.547 L5,10 L15,10 L15,15.547 Z M6,6 C6,3.794 7.794,2 10,2 C12.206,2 14,3.794 14,6 L14,8 L6,8 L6,6 Z M16,8 L16,6 C16,2.691 13.309,0 10,0 C6.691,0 4,2.691 4,6 L4,8 L3,8 L3,15.547 C3,16.208 3.222,16.859 3.626,17.381 L4.748,18.834 L4.749,18.834 C5.313,19.564 6.2,20 7.122,20 L12.878,20 C13.8,20 14.688,19.564 15.252,18.834 L16.374,17.381 C16.778,16.859 17,16.208 17,15.547 L17,8 L16,8 Z" fill="rgba(120, 117, 115, 1)" style="transition: fill 0.2s ease 0s;"></path><polygon points="9 16 11 16 11 12 9 12" fill="rgba(120, 117, 115, 1)" style="transition: fill 0.2s ease 0s;"></polygon></g></svg></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 1; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; flex-grow: 0; top: -16px; width: 100%;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); margin-left: 0px; pointer-events: none; padding-left: 0px; width: 100%; transform: translateY(14px);"><span style="max-width: 100%; color: rgb(120, 117, 115); font-family: &quot;Klarna Text&quot;, &quot;Klarna Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; line-height: 30px; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision; text-size-adjust: none;">CVC</span></div><input id="securityCode" name="securityCode" data-cid="card-security-code-field" autocomplete="cc-csc" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" spellcheck="false" value="" style="background-color: transparent; border: none; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; width: 100%; box-shadow: none; caret-color: rgb(72, 123, 148); color: rgb(23, 23, 23); font-family: &quot;Klarna Text&quot;, &quot;Klarna Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; height: 60px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 20px; position: absolute; text-overflow: ellipsis; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricprecision; transform: translateY(0px);"></div></div></label></div></div>
```

I tried using-

1. Actions class

   ```
   public void typeInField(String locator, String value) {
      String val = value;
      QAFWebElement element = getDriver().findElement(locator);
      element.clear();
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++) {
           char c = val.charAt(i);
           s = s.append(c);
          new Actions(getDriver()).sendKeys(element, s.toString()).build().perform();
     }
   }
   ```

2.JavascriptExecutor

```
getDriver().executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + data.get("number2").toString() + "';",
            getDriver().findElement("checkout.cardnumber.textbox"));
```

3. sendKeys

But seems like application application detects all these three as bot actions not human actions.
Is there other way so i can simulate the same action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now following solution working for me.

```
new Actions(getDriver()).sendKeys(getDriver().findElement(locator), Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.DELETE),"value_to_enter").build().perform();
```

Looking forward to get more answers.